# Database design for notification system

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, notifications

I read several questions about this argument here, but I can't find a solution.

The system has to send one o more notification to users, so my first idea is

```
Notification
---------------------
id
sender_id
message


Notification_user
--------------------
id
notification_id
recipient_id
is_read
created_on
read_on


User
---------------------
id
first_name
last_name
```

In `Notification` I can save message like "Walter White added a new article in 'Economy' section" and send it to users saved in `Notification_user`.

but in this way, there are two main problems:

1. If an user wants to receive the notification in a different language, I should saved the same message in different language.
2. If the message "Walter White added a new article in 'Economy' section" is saved in `Notification`, and then the admin changes the name of section from "Economy" to "Economy - Europe", the recipient will read the message with the old section name and not "Walter White added a new article in 'Economy - EUROPE' section"

So I thought to modify the `Notification` table in this way

```
Notification
----------------------
id
sender_id
extra_info
```

where in extra_info I concat a string that contains all info, for example: "sectionId:100,otherColumnId:125"

So, code side I can fetch the correct info, build the message and send it like a notification...but this approach should be expensive. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Try tackling one problem at a time

Comment: "Expensive"?  What makes you think that?  I suspect it is under 30 milliseconds.